# Can't publish report on Report Server. Unexpected Error Encountered

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, powerbi, reportserver

I'm trying to develop a custom authentication for Power BI Report Server and followed the following guide:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

It's OK. I can authenticate my own way, creating a kind of Single Sign On application. Although, I'm getting an error when I try to save a report as a Power BI Report Server on Power BI Desktop. I get Unexpected Error Encountered.

Does anyone know if this is really a problem with my authentication? In other server, same config, without Custom Authentication, everything works fine.

EDIT:

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU3Te.png)

Comment: Do the credentials your are using to deploy reports exist as credentials in the repository behind your custom security?

Comment: Also, you need to ensure you are giving your logins that need to deploy the proper authorization to publish in your override of Authorize(),

Comment: @RossBush How can I get the credentials I'm using to deploy? On Power BI I just "save as" Power BI Report Server.

Comment: If you are using custom security then you are bypassing normal SSRS security such as  basic auth, windows auth ,yada, yada. You have overridden it server wide. You will have manage authentication/authorization of your internal users in some fashion. You can test this by, ON A DEV BOX, returning true in both your Authenticate() and Authorize() functions. If you deploy your custom security dll to SSRS after making those changes then you should be able to deploy reports/access ssrs api without an issue.

Comment: Sorry about my unexperience with SSRS, including custom security, but I do not have those methods such as Authenticate or Authorize on my Microsoft.ReportingServices,Interfaces:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.reportingservices.interfaces.aspx

Comment: Are you entering credentials anytime prior to deploying in Power BI?

Comment: No. I just get the error on the image I updated the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161811/discussion-between-renan-vasconcelos-and-ross-bush).

Answer (score 2):

I did face similar issue, was unable to publish the Power BI reports to report server and was getting same error message "Unexpected Error Encountered"
To resolve this issue you launch your "Report Server Configuration Manager" on server where you have configured Power Bi Report server, and go to tab "Web Portal URL". The url which has been configured; copy it and go to your Power BI Desktop version -> go to File -> SaveAs -> Power Bi Report Server -> Paste the url in New report server address text box which you have copied.
sample url - http://IPaddress/ReportsPower or http://fqdn/ReportsPower
Click on OK button.
It will list you all the reports which are already available or if it fresh report then would show blank and would get Success message.

Please note that I have tried this on Power BI Desktop version - Version: 2.81.5831.1181 64-bit (May 2020)

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all add your server's IP/DomainName only (like 1.1.1.1 or example.com) in Windows credentials manager along with username and password, See the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxhyr.png)
2. Secondly click on file=>Save As=> Report Server give full address of report server like http://example.com/reports, See the screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeszX.png)

Comment: I did not have to add the IP/DomainName, but this may still be needed for others. Number 2 made it, my mistake was that I entered the full address that reached till the leaf folder where I wanted to save the report in. Yet, the menu wants you to enter only the main report server link, like "https://example.com/reports", and then click through the folder tree with the mouse until you reach the needed folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add your powerbi credential in credential manager under windows credential with power BI server URL.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blnr8.png)
I think this resolve your problem.

I have resolved this issue with this way.

Thanks

BennyRaja.A